# Filtering XML results using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Using jquery is it possible to filter XML results that are loaded?   Ideally i would like to do a mysql style filer/search like

```
SELECT * FROM "example_table" WHERE id="1"
```

I have an XML file loaded in to my application with the following structure

```
<country>
<state id="1">
    <statename>Baden-Wurttemberg</statename>
    <cities>
        <city>
            <cityname>Aach</cityname>
<yahoo>1</yahoo>
        </city>
```

Aalen
    2
            
        
    
    
I have multiple states (each with an "id") within my COUNTRY tag.  How can i get all cities  from state with id="1" using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't be able to use MySQL syntax without a plugin (if one exists), but you can just use jQuery selectors, then use map to turn it into a JS array of the cities:

```
var cities = $(xml).find('state[id=1] cityname')
                   .map(function(i,el){ return $(el).text() });
```